# Python Socket Received ASCII convert to actual numbers (float)

Tags: python, python-2.7

While using a Python socket connection and I received the following from the server (simulator):

```
'C\xbc\x7fZC\xbc\x7f5C\xbc\x7f&C\xbc\x7f!C\xbc\x7f\x14C\xbc\x7f\x16C\xbc\x7f!C\xbc\x7f\x12C\xbc\x7f\x19C\xbc\x80\x03C\xbc\x81~C\xbc\x80FC\xbc\x7f\xd1C\xbc~\xcdC\xbc~\xd7C\xbc\x7f$;4\xe0\xb8;\x81\xf6\xd7;R\xf4T:\xc5v\xb4:\xc1>\xc1:\xd9\x15\x9a:\xa8M7;K\xde{:\xfb\\\xcd\xbc\tR\xd4\xba\xe1\xb6\xf3\xbb\xc9\xb8\xf4\xbby\x8a\x199\x9dH\x009\x0cp\x00:\xeb<\x00'
```

But my actual output should be (size 32x1):

```
376.99493   376.99380   376.99335   376.99319   376.99280   376.99286
376.99319   376.99274   376.99295   377.00009   377.01166   377.00214
376.99857   376.99063   376.99094   376.99329   0.0027599763
0.0039661932    0.0032189088    0.0015065284    0.0014743434
0.0016562224    0.0012840395    0.0031107950    0.0019177437
-0.0083815642   -0.0017220661   -0.0061560813   -0.0038076697
0.00029999018   0.00013393164   0.0017946959
```

How can I convert the ASCII codes to get those numbers in Python 2.7.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the floats from a socket, you can use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

#### Code:

```
num_floats = int(len(raw_data) / 4)
format_str = '>' + 'f' * num_floats
data = struct.unpack(format_str, raw_data[:num_floats * 4])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import struct

raw_data = b'C\xbc\x7fZC\xbc\x7f5C\xbc\x7f&C\xbc\x7f!C\xbc\x7f\x14C\xbc' \
           b'\x7f\x16C\xbc\x7f!C\xbc\x7f\x12C\xbc\x7f\x19C\xbc\x80\x03C' \
           b'\xbc\x81~C\xbc\x80FC\xbc\x7f\xd1C\xbc~\xcdC\xbc~\xd7C\xbc' \
           b'\x7f$;4\xe0\xb8;\x81\xf6\xd7;R\xf4T:\xc5v\xb4:\xc1>\xc1:\xd9' \
           b'\x15\x9a:\xa8M7;K\xde{:\xfb\\xcd\xbc\tR\xd4\xba\xe1\xb6\xf3' \
           b'\xbb\xc9\xb8\xf4\xbby\x8a\x199\x9dH\x009\x0cp\x00:\xeb'

num_floats = int(len(raw_data) / 4)
format_str = '>' + 'f' * num_floats
data = struct.unpack(format_str, raw_data[:num_floats * 4])

print(data)
```

#### Results:

```
(376.99493408203125, 376.9938049316406, 376.99334716796875,
 376.9931945800781, 376.9927978515625, 376.99285888671875,
 376.9931945800781, 376.99273681640625, 376.9929504394531,
 377.0000915527344, 377.01165771484375, 377.00213623046875,
 376.9985656738281, 376.9906311035156, 376.9909362792969, 
 376.9932861328125, 0.00275997631251812, 0.003966193180531263, 
 0.0032189087942242622, 0.001506528351455927, 0.0014743433566763997, 
 0.001656222390010953, 0.001284039462916553, 0.003110795048996806, 
 0.0019177338108420372, 4.2194070097596986e+21, 456834187264.0, 
 -7.263825409609126e-06, -0.00011669746163534, -7.377517891143851e-33, 
 131300.1875, 1.5874123484317317e+29)
```