# Convert bytes received by socket to float in Python 3

Tags: python, struct, byte, ascii

I've tried following the suggested answer here but did not get the intended result:
[Python Socket Received ASCII convert to actual numbers (float)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482466/python-socket-received-ascii-convert-to-actual-numbers-float)

I'm receiving data in bytes format like so, using socket.recv():

```
      b'(1,3,-121.551552,-123.602531,-40.582172,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)'
```

I'm trying to receive the values above as a list of 30 floats.

I understand we have to use the struct library but I'm facing difficulties trying to grasp the concept of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your incoming floats aren't fixed-length, apart from having 6 decimal paces, if at all. So why not just use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), then strip off the brackets and then split on commas?

With each step broken down:

```
>>> b = b'(1,3,-121.551552,-123.602531,-40.582172,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)'
>>> b.decode()
'(1,3,-121.551552,-123.602531,-40.582172,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)'
>>> b.decode()[1:-1]
'1,3,-121.551552,-123.602531,-40.582172,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
>>> b.decode()[1:-1].split(',')
['1', '3', '-121.551552', '-123.602531', '-40.582172', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
 '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
>>> [float(x) for x in b.decode()[1:-1].split(',')]
[1.0, 3.0, -121.551552, -123.602531, -40.582172, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

And a more *Pythonic* way to do that last one-step:

```
>>> list(map(float, b.decode()[1:-1].split(',')))
[1.0, 3.0, -121.551552, -123.602531, -40.582172, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```